# opamp instead LDO

Tags: power, operational-amplifier, adc, analog, ldo

I have very tough requirements on noise (sub mV, no 50Hz allowed) and LDO seem to fail in that. The required current is like 20-40mA, so i am thinking about using opamp with reference voltage.

Is there any showstopper for that? Maybe, somebody did it before?

Comment: What if I told you that an LDO is basically an opamp with a reference ?! So how do you think that your solution will be any better than any LDO ? What LDOs have you considered ? Have you looked at low noise references like the ADR4550 ? Your specification is lacking: input voltage, required PSRR, what about 1/f noise ?? sub mV noise is easy, no 50 Hz is impossible. There will always be 50 Hz. Specify what is acceptable like 10 nVrms for example.

Comment: Sure, the opamp will work. (I've done it with a external pass transistor for more current.)  Filter the reference heavily.  For really low noise add a transistor capacitance multiplier on the output.

Comment: Could also cascade two LDO's to double PSRR.

Comment: Yes, I have used this. Have a look at the reference design of the ADS1282 from TI (http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/sbau144). On page 29 you will find the power supply. It has been built by a high precision reference followed by a opamp.

Comment: There are some very low noise LDOs avilable, look at Analog and Hittite, which are head and shoulders above examples from (say) Micrel. For the very lowest noise, a low noise transistor design is what you need. However, a low noise opamp with follower will come close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main gotcha is that op-amp stability with capacitive load is often dubious at best- if you do this you can add extra compensation or use a special op-amp that is guaranteed stable with nF of capacitive load. Connecting an ordinary op-amp voltage follower to a reference will typically result in oscillation when the bypass capacitors are added to the output, and op-amps have pretty high output resistance at high frequencies (tens of ohms) so you usually **need** bypass capacitors.

We never have a problem with 50Hz noise here, but 60Hz (or 120Hz) can be a possibility.

Personally, I don't think you should do that, there are LDOs available with a few uV of noise (eg. LP5907). If you don't like the 90dB PSRR at 100Hz, add another regulator in front of it (doesn't have to be a great one) and it should be undetectable, **if** your layout is good. If uV of noise is too much, then add some passive filtering afterwards or, as GH says, a capacitive multiplier.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I have understood and experienced what you have explained here. I generated 1.65V reference from an opamp and it oscillated. Now i will re design the circuit. You suggest using low noise LDO like LP5907 am i right. The link of my problem i previously asked about is here:https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/695878/differential-signal-amplification-with-op-amp-dc-biasing-problem