# Differential Signal Amplification with Op-Amp DC Biasing Problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, differential-amplifier

The example circuit on the schematic generates square wave like output and the signal appears at the top of that square wave (see the scope output screenshot).

All i need is to amplify differential signal while converting it to a single ended signal and place it on a 1.65V fix dc bias voltage to be able to sample it with 0-3.3V ADC.

What is the reason of this output.

[LT1817 Datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/181567fb.pdf)

[image: example schematic]
[image: Scope output]
[image: dc bias circuit]
[image: differential signal source]

Comment: What actually connects to the node labeled DC_BIAS and, what does your input signal actually look like? Please provide a link to the data sheet of the LT1817S.

Comment: I have added schematics and the link.

Comment: LT1817 datasheet -> "On a single 5V supply, the output swings from 1V to 4V"

Comment: Yes i see that. What does it mean exactly. I mean is that swing the reason of all this behaviour.

Comment: This opamp is meant for +/-5V supplies. On +5V/0V supplies the output won't go lower than 1V, so you lose the bottom third of your 3.3V ADC between 0V and 1V. You'd need an opamp that can output 0V, so either rail to rail output, or single supply opamp whose output range includes ground but not necessarily up to 5V since that's not needed for the ADC. I'm having trouble making sense of the scope screenshot...

Comment: Also even with no signal the input common mode range is very close to the limits of the opamp and that would be a better explanation for this scope shot which does not look like simple clipping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take note of this stated in the data sheet (page 12) regarding the LT1817 you have attempted to use for generating a DC mid-rail voltage (DC_BIAS): -

> **The LT1815/LT1816/LT1817 are optimized for high bandwidth and low
> distortion applications. They can drive a capacitive load of 10pF in a
> unity-gain configuration and more with higher gain.**

In other words, that op-amp (with 100 nF on the output) will turn into an oscillator and, you'll get the likely strange behaviour you see.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Andy.